# Wordpress & Django -- One domain, two servers. Possible?

Tags: python, django, apache

My question is about hosting Django and Wordpress under one domain, but two physical machines (actually, they are VMs but same diff).

Let's say I have a Django webapp at example.com.  I'd like to start a Wordpress blog about my webapp, so any blog page rank mojo flows back to my webapp, I'd like the blog address t be example.com/blog.  My understanding is blog.example.com would not transfer said page rank mojo.

Because I'm worried about Wordpress security flaws compromising my Django webapp, I want to host Django and Wordpress on two physically separate machines.

Given all that, is it possible using re-write rules or a reverse proxy server to do this?  I know the easy way is to make my Wordpress blog a subdomain, but I really don't want to do that.

Has anyone done this in the past, is it stable?  If I need a third server to be a dedicated reverse proxy, that's totally fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Partial answer: If you're using HTTPS (you better for Wordpress and Django admin), look into wildcard certs. You could host websites on separate machines and have one of the machines Proxy a VirtualHost to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with haproxy -- a robust software load balancer:

```
global
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
#  chroot /usr/share/haproxy
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  daemon
  log 127.0.0.1 local0 info

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option redispatch
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  balance roundrobin
  retries 3
  contimeout 5000
  clitimeout 600000
  srvtimeout 600000

frontend http_proxy :80
  acl path_foo path_beg /foo
  use_backend foo if path_foo
  default_backend www

backend foo
  server foo0 127.0.0.1:8080

backend www
  server www0 127.0.0.1:8081
```